# java generics for array and String

Tags: java

I need to write a single generic method which can take both an array and a String reference. Inside such method, depending on the argument, I need to check for equality as well as do indexing. For array, the indexing is of course `[] operator`, but for String, it is `charAt()` method. Besides, I want to iterate over the argument, so for array I will be using `length` field and for String I will be using `length()` method. For equality, I need to use `equals()` method for array and `==` for chars in the String.

Is it something I'd better off write two separate overloaded methods, or it is worth the efforts to make it a generic method.

If in the latter case, how to do this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this method?

Comment: Overload; you're taking different types.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java are objects, so you can write a method that receive one Object and test using the "instanceof" function.

```
public class MethodTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tst = new String[]{"SOME","TEXT"};
    doSomething( tst );
    doSomething("TEST");
}

public static void doSomething( Object o ) {
    if( o instanceof String ) {
        System.out.println( (String) o );
    } else if( o instanceof String[] ) {
        String something[] = (String[]) o;
        for( String s : something ) {
            System.out.println( s );
        }
    }
}

}
```

But I think two methods will be a best approach...

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, you're almost certainly better off writing two overloaded methods.

It is unclear what -- if anything -- would be gained by combining them into one. However, doing that would probably require a non-trivial amount of effort and the result will likely be pretty convoluted.

Besides, a single method that can take both an array and a `String` would have to take `Object` as its argument. Once you accept `Object`, people will be able to call your method with *lots* of things it won't know how to deal with; instead of compile-time failures, the combined method would have to fail at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to achieve the same for `char[]`-s and `String`-s. It does not worth to write the generic method (imo, because of the lack of operator overloading in java), but you can easily convert the `char[]` to `String`(or vice versa) then execute the same code, if it is ok.

Comment: not necessarily char[], I may use some fancy objects `myObjs[]` for which `equals()` is overriden. :)

Comment: In this case, definitely different methods. (Because of the lack of overloading), but I can't imagine a situation when you do the same thing for string literal types and "other" types.

Answer (score 0):

Overload the method. The effort in solving that in a generic way will be waste and most likely  unreadable.